# webpack: missing external configuration for type:commonjs

Tags: webpack

### the errorInfo is

**Error in chunk columns/index [entry]**

**columns/index.js**

**missing external configuration for type:commonjs**

when i update webpack version to 4, i get this. i can't find what that means. I excluded the reason why es was downgraded

here is webpack.config.js

```
const utils = require('./utils')
const CopyWebpackExternalsManifest = require('copy-webpack-externals-manifest')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  entry: utils.entry("./app/src/**/index.js"),
  output: utils.output,
  plugins: [
    ...utils.plugins,
    new CopyWebpackExternalsManifest({
      externals: [{
        module: "lodash",
        entry: ["lodash.min.js"],
        export: {
          root: "_",
          commonjs2: 'lodash'
        }
      }, {
        module: "jquery",
        entry: ["dist/jquery.min.js"],
        export: {
          root: "$",
          commonjs2: 'jquery'
        }
      }, {
        module: "tinymce",
        entry: ["tinymce.min.js"],
        export: {
          root: "tinymce",
          commonjs2: 'tinymce'
        },
        assets: ["plugins", "themes/modern", "skins"]
      }, {
        module: "plupload",
        entry: ["js/plupload.full.min.js"],
        export: {
          root: "plupload",
          commonjs2: 'plupload'
        },
        assets: ["js/moxie.min.js"]
      }, {
        module: "moment",
        entry: ["min/moment.min.js"],
        export: {
          root: "moment",
          commonjs2: 'moment'
        }
      }, {
        module: "vue",
        entry: [utils.vueRuntimeByEnv],
        export: {
          root: "Vue",
          commonjs2: 'vue'
        }
      }, {
        module: "element-ui",
        entry: ["lib/index.js", "lib/theme-chalk/index.css"],
        export: {
          root: "ELEMENT",
          commonjs2: 'element-ui'
        },
        assets: ["lib/theme-chalk/fonts"]
      }, {
        module: "vue-echarts",
        entry: ["dist/vue-echarts.js"],
        export: {
          root: "VueECharts",
          commonjs2: 'vue-echarts'
        }
      }
      ]
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader"
              ]
            }, {
              test: /\.less/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "less-loader"
              ]
            }
          ],
          preserveWhitespace: false,
          postcss: [
            require('autoprefixer')({
              browsers: ['last 5 versions']
            })
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

here is the target js:columns/index.js

```
import Vue from '../constructor';
import index from './index.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(index),
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the reason, i found that i had set the libraryTarget of output in the configuration of wepback

```
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

but in externals

```
 externals: {
  lodash: {
    commonjs: 'lodash',
    commonjs2: 'lodash',
    amd: 'lodash',
    root: '_'
  }
}
```

i forget set commonjs, so i add commonjs, the problem was solved